# Como filtrar entradas de dados no PHP

Tags: php, html, xss

Boa noite, tenho um formulário servindo de entrada de dados que é exibido na tela. 
O problema é que esses dados podem ser tags html ou scripts, se alguém colocar esse código no meu formulário, a pagina vai ser redirecionada.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="6; url=http://pt.stackoverflow.com/">
```

Como eu poderia limpar as tags html ou qualquer outro tipo de injeção maliciosa ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Resposta objetiva !

**strip_tags()** permite outros tipos de inserção de [XSS](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) então use **htmlspecialchars()**

```
echo htmlspecialchars($Variavel, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

### Resposta longa.....

Vamos começar por partes, o que você quer e se proteger do [XSS](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), sua entrada de dados está possibilitando a injeção de comandos ou marcações, vamos analisar isso bem para conseguir criar uma solução 100% funcional, em segurança devemos ser calculistas.

### Analisando o cenário onde XSS pode acontecer!

Vamos colocar dois cenários para essa situação

```
<input type="text" value="$Suspeito">
```

e um outra bem comum é quando colocamos o conteúdo em uma div

```
<div class="container" id="ct">
    <?php echo $Suspeito ?>
</div>
```

Agora, vamos substituir, essa variável por um clássico do xss

Não funciona !

```
<input type="text" value="<script> alert("Xss here");</script> ">
```

Funciona !

```
<div class="container" id="ct">
        <script> alert("Xss here");</script> 
    </div>
```

### Solução a primeira vista!

Podemos adicionar uma proteção extra usando strip_tags() para escapar as tags !

Vamos ver como ficaria se nossa variável tive-se uma proteção com strip_tags()

Não funciona !

```
<input type="text" value="alert("Xss here"); ">
```

Não funciona !

```
<div class="container" id="ct">
         alert("Xss here"); 
    </div>
```

Assim como no brasil, existe jeitinho para tudo e essa solução está longe de resolver algum problema, basta você usar sua imaginação.

imagine essa situação, aparentemente não existe problemas certo ?

Errado, vamos forçar nossa imaginação, preciso ferrar com esse código sem usar  tags

```
<?php $Suspeito = '" onfocus=document.write("");" fecha="';
<input type="text" value="" onfocus=document.write("");" fecha="">
```

Opa, agora deu problema será que é apenas esse ?

```
';alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//';alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//";
alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//";alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//--
></SCRIPT>">'><SCRIPT>alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))</SCRIPT>


'';!--"<XSS>=&{()}

<IMG SRC="javascript:alert('XSS');">

<IMG SRC=&#0000106&#0000097&#0000118&#0000097&#0000115&#0000099&#0000114&#0000105&#0000112&#0000116&#0000058&#0000097&
#0000108&#0000101&#0000114&#0000116&#0000040&#0000039&#0000088&#0000083&#0000083&#0000039&#0000041>
```

Então, então precisamos de outra solução que não falhe dessa forma, Lembrando que temos outro problema, se você escapar as tags, ninguém vai conseguir usar... lembre-se matemática,comparações, ou até mesmo código, você simplesmente vai perder dados...

### Solução mais flexível

Limitando codificação a  UTF-8 e usando o htmlspecialchars, se torna possível a utilização de tags e scripts no html sem que tenha algum efeito na pagina, o caracteres são dissubstituídos por entidades <> vão virar <> totalmente transparente ao usuário.

```
echo htmlspecialchars($Suspeito, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Olhe esse link mostrando uma comparação entre  htmlspecialchars vs strip_tags [Script online](http://ideone.com/Er5UZZ)

Essa talvez não seja uma solução perfeita, talvez exista uma forma de burlar, tente fazer isso sempre que se deparar com alguma questão de segurança,olhe para seu código é pense "posso burlar isso ? "

Comment: Mas estou usando e não esta retornando nada <?php echo htmlspecialchars($exibe_tarefas , ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>

Comment: Atualizei o exemplo usando uma array, veja 
http://ideone.com/Er5UZZ

Answer (score 4):

Você quer saber como é que faz para tirar essas tags, caso o usuário insira isto no campo text para adicionar no banco de dados mysql, evitando redirecionamentos desnecessários no ECHO, estou certo?

**Se SIM**
Pode usar `strip_tags()` função que retira tags html de strings.

Comment: Isso que procurava thanks <?php echo strip_tags( $exibe_tarefas [ "tarefa" ] ); ?>

Comment: Caso deseje retirar apenas esta tag, você pode usar expressões regulares com a função preg_match();

Comment: Sim agora descobri ate o fgetss

Comment: Xss... vivendo e aprendendo

Comment: Sim exato, existem **N** maneiras... rsrsrs, qualquer coisa estamos a disposição.

Comment: @ItaloIzaac Boa edição na questão, apesar de você ter feito o serviço e não ter deixado o autor aprender por si só. Porém agora está uma boa questão.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento tudo bem, mas não vejo problema tão grande em dar uma dica mais em cima de algo, até porque as vezes usuários correm atras de respostas rápidas. Assim, deve partir dela o estudo, até porque conteúdo na internet não falta, mas vindo aqui ela teria uma certa urgência, e fica até como referência para ela.

Comment: A pergunta era bem confusa de inicio e realmente eu estava orientando ele a editar para que obtivesse respostas mais rápidas e que outros usuários criassem interesse em respondê-la. Felizmente você teve a boa vontade e responder, mas o autor não vai ter sempre alguém a disposição e quando isso ocorre ele irá ficar frustrado. Espero que entenda.

Comment: Perfeitamente. :D

Comment: @ItaloIzaac
Essa solução não abrange os dados que são colocados nos atributos, alem de tirar a liberdade de usar as tags, qualquer referencia a matemática ou a até mesmo a programação vai ser removida,  Exemplo de String onde a falha persiste 
  " onfocus=document.write("");"  vai continuar funcionando -> <input value="<?php echo $Variavel ?> ">

Answer (score 4):

Existem formas e formas de resolver problemas, eu pessoalmente prefiro recorrer ao [PHP do jeito certo](http://br.phptherightway.com/) ao se tratar do PHP, pois na própria linguagem existem inúmeras soluções para problemas cotidianos, onde normalmente são feitos malabarismos para chegar a mesma solução.

Sempre quando obtiver uma informação de fonte não conhecida, como por exemplo do envio de informação de um formulário, sempre deverá ser tratada a informação de entrada e saída, sendo ela enviada ou recebida de um banco de dados ou na própria página HTML.

Na linguagem PHP existe os [filtros](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.filter.php), que são utilizados para validar (como no caso da validação de e-mail através do filtro FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) e higienizar os valores (como no caso do FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, que limpa strings e FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL que limpa caracteres que não são utilizados na construção de um e-mail). Esses filtros trabalham em conjunto com a função [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-var.php), [filter_input](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php) e outros.

Levando em consideração a documentação do PHP e a [Referência do PHP do jeito certo](http://br.phptherightway.com/#filtro_de_dados) eu utilizaria o exemplo abaixo:

```
<?php

//inseguro
$input = 'alert("ola")';
echo $input;

//seguro
$input_filter = filter_var($input, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
echo "<br>". $input_filter;
```

Exemplo no ideone: http://ideone.com/Y2w9tr